# Add operator to third-party type?

Tags: c#, types, operator-overloading

I have a third-party library (Mogre), in which is a struct (Vector3). I would like to add an overload for the '+' operator (no override needed) for this type but am not sure how.

I cannot use extension methods as it is an operator I want to extend; the class is not `sealed` but not `partial` either, so if I try and define it again with my new operator overload I get conflicts.

Is it possible to extend a type like this? What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Try by extending this class and make it the base class of a custom class in which you define the operators overload

Comment: But then he'd have to use the operator overload between the sub classes, not with the base classes.

Comment: You say Vector3 is a struct, but then say the class is not sealed or partial...  is it a struct or a class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add an operator overload to a third-party type -- really any class you don't have the ability to edit.  Operator overloads must be defined inside their type they are to operate on (at least one of the args).  Since it's not your type, you can't edit it, and `struct`s cannot be extended.

But, even if it was a non-`sealed class`, you'd have to sub-class, which would ruin the point because they you'd have to use the subclass and not the superclass with the operator, since you can't define the operator overload between the base types...

```
public class A
{
    public int X { get; set; }
}

public class B : A
{
    public static A operator + (A first, A second)
    {
        // this won't compile because either first or second must be type B...
    }
}
```

You could do the overload completely between instances of the subclass, but then you'd have to use your new subclass wherever you wanted to do the overload instead of the original superclass, which would look clunky and probably not what you want:

```
public class A
{
    public int X { get; set; }
}

public class B : A
{
    public static B operator + (B first, B second)
    {
        // You could do this, but then you'd have to use the subclass B everywhere you wanted to
        // do this instead of the original class A, which may be undesirable...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. (Sorry, I never tried to use those modifiers with a struct def. before and wasn't aware that they were not permissible with structs) For this any readability gains would be offset by having using a subclass half the time as you say, but certainly worth it for more complex extensions.